# Net force acting on current loop in $B$ field linearly dependent $z$

Tags: electromagnetism, coordinate-systems, magnetic-moment

Suppose there is a magnetic field  $\overline B$, only in the $z$ direction and dependent linearly in $z$ coordinate e.g. $$\overline B=(0,0,B_0*z)$$  $B_0$ is a constant.

And a circular current loop in the B field with current $I$ ,oriented to $x$-$y$ plane (the magnetic moment point to  $\hat z$ direction).

The question is what the total force acting on the loop?

I try two ways to solve the problem but I got two different answers.

In one way I used $-\nabla(\overline\mu_B*\overline B)$ and I got a non zero value of the force $$ F_{net}=-\mu_B*B_0$$
$$\mu_B=I*\pi*r^2$$

r is the radius of the loop.

The second way I try it is to calculate the following integral:$$F_{net}= I*\int d\overline r X \overline B$$
Because the B is only in the z direction and the current loop is in x-y plane, the B that the loop feels is constant , so the resulting force need to cancel and we need to get zero like uniform magnetic field.

what I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*what I missing here?*

**1** *Suppose there is a magnetic field $\vec B$, only in the $z$ direction*

and

**2** *dependent linearly in z coordinate*

e.g.

**3** $\vec B=(0,0,B_0\,z)$

Statements $1,\,2$ and $3$ cannot be all correct.

If the magnetic field is increasing in the $z$ direction then the magnetic field lines must get closer together as $z$ increases which means that they cannot be parallel.

In this example there is a net force $(=\mu_{\rm B}\, B_0)$ on the magnetic dipole moment.

In the second method you must take note that the magnetic field is inclined to the magnetic dipole.

[image]

Comment: So according to what you say, B cant be both parallel and nonuniform?

Comment: That is correct.  Think about it in terms of density of magnetic field lines which must change if the magnetic field is non uniform.

Comment: So for E field also it cant be both parallel and non-uniform?

Comment: @Joseph4321 It is also true for an electric field.

Answer (score 0):

The torque of on a magnetic moment $\vec{\mu}$ from an external $\vec{B}$ field is
$$\vec{\tau} = \vec{\mu} \times \vec{B}$$

since both $\vec{\mu}$ and $\vec{B}$ point in the direction $\hat{z}$ we have
$\hat{z} \times \hat{z} = \vec{0}$. There is no force on the loop.

Comment: The magnetic field is not uniform. Please look at my answer.

Comment: Torque is zero but I ask about the net force.